# Drools rule to compare two fields of two pojos

Tags: java, drools

i've got the following Java classes:

```
public class A {

    private String text;

    public A(){
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text=text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }   

}
```

and

```
public class B {

    private A firstField;
    private A secondField;
    private Boolean success = false;

    public B(){
    }

    public void setFirstField(A firstField) {
        this.firstField=firstField;
    }

    public A getFirstField(){
        return firstField;
    }

    public void setSecondField(A secondField) {
        this.secondField=secondField;
    }

    public A getSecondField(){
        return secondField;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success=success;
    }

    public Boolean isSuccess(){
        return success;
    }       

}
```

i'm trying to write a Drools rule that will allow me to compare the text attribute of firstField to that of secondField in class B. This is my java code:

```
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("myrule.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
    KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
    StatelessKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
    B obj = new B();
    ksession.execute(obj);
```

and these are the contents of myrule.drl:

```
package test
import my.package.A
import my.package.B

rule "myrule"
no-loop
    when
        $obj : B(firstField.getText().equals(secondField.getText()))
    then
        modify($obj){
            setSuccess((Boolean)true);
        }
end
```

which is unfortunatelly not working, what am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: "Not working" due to strike? - Works for me, using Drools 6.3.0. - Your version, stack trace or error message etc., please.

Answer (score 0):

It is really strange that your code even compile because `ksession.execute()` expects a `Command<T>` and not a simple `B`: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.6.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch03.html#d0e3581
In your simple scenario, what you are looking for (I guess) is a Command to insert the `B` object and another to fire all the rules.
You can achieve this by using a `BatchExcecution` command:

```
B obj = new B();
List cmds = new ArrayList();        
cmds.add( CommandFactory.newInsertObject(obj) );
ksession.execute( CommandFactory.newBatchExecution( cmds ) );
```

In the exampleabove, the fire all rules command is implicit.

Hope it helps,